# Python program that gets basic information on a Github user

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I've created a basic Python CLI script, which takes a Github username, and returns some basic information associated with said username. I use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for HTTP requests (I'm new to this area) and [docopt](http://docopt.org/) for command-line handling.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Github User Info

Get basic information on a Github user

Usage:
  github_user_info.py USERNAME
  github_user_info.py (-h | --help)
  github_user_info.py (-v | --version)

Arguments:
  USERNAME     Github username

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -v --version  Show version.
"""

from docopt import docopt
import requests

import sys


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        sys.argv.append('-h')  # Show help screen if no arguments are passed

    cmd_arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Github User Info v1.0')

    username = cmd_arguments["USERNAME"]

    if len(username.split()) != 1:
        print('Github usernames must be one word in length! Exiting!')
        return

    response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}')

    if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        if response.status_code == 404:  # No such user was found
            print(f'No Github user was found with username {username}!')
        else:
            print(f'An unexpected error occured! Exiting with error code: '
                  f'{response.status_code}')
        return

    responses_json = response.json()

    print(f'The following information was found on user: {username}',
          end='\n\n')
    print(f'Name: {responses_json["name"]}')
    print(f'Bio: {responses_json["bio"]}')
    print(f'Followers: {responses_json["followers"]}')
    print(f'Following: {responses_json["following"]}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd mainly like to know if this is the correct way to handle HTTP requests (in terms of getting them, error handling, etc.). I'd also like to make sure that I follow good Python conventions.

Comment: as a side note, if you want to pursue the project further, see the pygithub project !

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer Yeah, I've seen that project, but I personally don't want to use it, as my goal is to learn more about HTTP requests, not the Github API specifically. Plus, the documentation is sparse, at best.

Comment: yes docs are lacking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note:
instead of using `string.split()` to check for spaces, you can directly check with `in`.

From:

> ```
> if len(username.split()) != 1:
>         print('Github usernames must be one word in length! Exiting!')
>         return
> ```

To:

```
if ' ' in username:
        print('Github usernames cannot contain spaces! Exiting!')
        return
```

Also, instead of multiple print statements, you can use multiline strings: `"""`...`"""` or `'''`...`'''`.

From:

> ```
> print(f'The following information was found on user: {username}',
>       end='\n\n')
> print(f'Name: {responses_json["name"]}')
> print(f'Bio: {responses_json["bio"]}')
> print(f'Followers: {responses_json["followers"]}')
> print(f'Following: {responses_json["following"]}')
> ```

To:

```
print(f'''
The following information was found on user: {username}

Name: {responses_json["name"]}
Bio: {responses_json["bio"]}
Followers: {responses_json["followers"]}
Following: {responses_json["following"]}''')
```